# Expected power of random vector by matrix

Tags: matrices, vectors, normal-distribution, expected-value

I need to find the expected power of **Y** = **A X** where **X**~CN(**0**,**I**) and **A** is a complex matrix.
Can anybody help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The definition of power of a random vector is the expected value of the squared norm of the vector: $E(||y||^2)$.

Moreover,  $||y||^2=y^H y$.

Now we calculate $E(|(|y|)|^2 )=E(x^H A^H Ax)$. Then since

$Tr(ABCD) = Tr(DABC) = Tr(CDAB)=...$

and because expectation and trace can be interchanged we can proceed as follows. Also note that $a = Tr(a)$ if $a$ is a scalar (and $x^H A^H Ax$ is a scalar). Then we get

$E(x^H A^H Ax) = E(Tr(x^H A^H Ax))= E(Tr(A^H Axx^H)) = Tr(E(A^H Axx^H))= Tr(A^H AE(xx^H))= Tr(A^H A)$

which gives the solution.